# Struts checkbox values cant be zero

Tags: struts, actionform

I have a set of checkboxes, If I check or uncheck them on the form the setCheckboxes method in  Action form gets fired after it gets posted. But it doesnt fire when ALL the checkboxes have been unchecked. How do get it to do that?

Comment: then put a hidden variable in jsp which indicates all atleast one check box is checked.based on that condition call that method in action

Comment: i think it will solve your problem

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes aren't submitted; that's just how HTTP works. The comment saying to use some type of hidden value is the general workaround, but it's unclear (a) what's happening and (b) what you *want* to happen. The form will be submitted regardless of checkbox values.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is, if the checkbox is unchecked struts wont populate it.

if you are having the particular field as boolean in your form class you can use a javascript 
function to find the unchecked checkboxes and try to append the value as false in the url.

eg.

```
http://youraction.do?checkBox1=false&checkBox2=false
```

this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of depending on javascript or some workaround to get false values to be sent, just assume the values will be false (override the reset() method to set all to false) and any that are checked will be submitted and setCheckbox() will be called.

Was there some other reason you wanted setCheckbox to be called?

Comment: Steve, I want setCheckbox to be called even if there aren't any checked. Yes , there is a reason.